# Set icon in selected date picker form css

Tags: css

I try to set icon (font-awesome) into the left selected date picker form, but it doesn't appear. How can i do it?

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <input 
    class="date-pick form-control " data-date-format="d/m/yyyy" type="text" 
    name="date1" placeholder="Select a date " autocomplete="OFF" 
    required="required" readonly="">
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you have 'fa' class applied? usually font-awsome classes are applied to get the icons. ex: `<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved like that.

**html code**

```
    <div class="form-group dayselect bookingdates">
                            <input class="date-pick form-control bookingdate" 
    name="date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" autocomplete="OFF" value=" 
    {{\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay(1)->format('d/m/Y')}}"  type="text" readonly  
    required>
                        </div>
```

**css code**

```
    .bookingdates {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
    }
    .bookingdates:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';    content: '\f073';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1a2b49;
    }
    .bookingdates input
    {
    padding-left: 35px;
    }
```